# SQL Server: How to make a self-join with a case command more efficient?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data structure in a table containing 56 Million rows.
Here is how it is structured:

```
create table #table (
    researcher nvarchar(20),
    unit nVARCHAR(20),
    paper int,
    general_type nvarchar(20));
insert into #table (researcher,
                    unit,
                    paper,
                    general_type)
Values ('R1', 'A', 1, 'O'),
('R1', 'A', 2, 'O'),
('R1', 'A', 3, 'O'),
('R1', 'B', 4, 'N'),
('R1', 'B', 5, 'N'),
('R1', 'B', 6, 'N'),
('R2', 'B', 7, 'O'),
('R2', 'B', 8, 'O'),
('R2', 'A', 9, 'N');
```

The task is to perform an inner join on the same table (i.e., joining the table with itself and perform a case based on the `general_type` column in the table. Currently I am doing like so:

```
select a.researcher,
       a.unit as unit_source,
       b.unit as unit_target,
       a.paper,
       a.general_type as general_type_source,
       b.general_type as general_type_target,
       case
       when a.unit = b.unit then 'Resident'
       else case
            when a.general_type = 'O'
            and b.general_type  = 'N' then 'Before' 
            else case
                when a.general_type = 'N'
                and b.general_type  = 'O' then 'After' 
                else case
                    when a.general_type = 'N'
                    and b.general_type  = 'N' then 'Before'
                    else case
                            when a.general_type = 'O'
                            and b.general_type  = 'O'
                            and a.unit != b.unit then 'Before' 
       else 'error' end end end end end as relationship
  from #table as a
  join #table as b
    on a.researcher = b.researcher;
```

The problem is that the current query creates a table that becomes too large for the database system (1.5 Terabytes of data).

I need to create the table in a more effective way without using 1.5 Terabytes of temp space. How can I do this, without compromising on the output as I need all the records.

Comment: have you tried to split the query up an union the part as they are mutually exlusivem you can use the case option to filter the joins

Comment: @nbk haven't tried it yet, will try it now

Comment: Do you *need* `distinct` as that is going to slow it down and force a hash or sort. 56-million-row cross join is going to be massive whichever way you do it, I suggest you rethink this and work out what you are actually trying to achieve (unclear here)

Comment: If this is something you really want to do, it would work better on a "big data" cloud platform. For example Azure SQL Hyperscale. You'll need to pay, but you'll get a platform that scales up to do what you need, and you can stop paying when you've finished your analysis. If this is something you do regularly you might want to look into technologies like databricks, which is a bit of a learning curve, but lends itself to processing large datasets.

Comment: My other comment is: what are you doing with this 1.5 Terabytes of data? what's the next step here?